Modifiying a sequence of measures to assign a certain value when integrating a fixed function?
Let $f:\mathbb R ^d\to \mathbb R$ be some continuous function, $|f|\leq A(1+|x|)$, where $|\cdot|$ denotes the usual Euclidean norm. Fix a measure $\mu$ and constant $C$.
Assume that $\mu_n$ is a sequence of probability measures with compact support (not necessarily common), all of them having mean $M$, and satisfying $W_1(\mu_n,\mu)< C$. We also know that:  $\mu_n\to\mu_{\infty}$ in $W_1$ distance (in particular, this implies $\int f d\mu_n\to\int f d\mu_\infty$).
Is there a way to construct another sequence of measures $\nu_n$ such that:
$$\text{supp}(\nu_n)\text{ compact,}\text{ mean}(\nu_n)=M,W_1(\nu_n,\mu)< C,\nu_n\to\mu_\infty,\int f d\nu_n=\int f d\mu_{\infty}$$
Motivation: I had a similar situation where I only knew that the sequence has compact support, was inside a 1-Wasserstein ball of radius $C$ and has $\int x d\mu_n\to M$. In this case, I simply considered the sequence $\nu_n=\mu_n*\delta_{M-\text{mean}(\mu_n)}$. The measures still have compact support, are still in the open ball (after potentially skipping finitely many initial elements) and now they all have mean exactly equal to $M$. I was hoping that a similar thing could be done here.
Any ideas and suggestions are greatly appreciated!
Many thanks in advance!

Would you be more precise about "a way to alter the measures"?

Yeah sure! I guess I simply mean produce a new sequence of measures which satisfies the three listed properties of the old sequence and satisfies the additional property $\int f d \nu_n=R$. I do not really care about how the sequence is constructed, but I am guessing $\mu_n$ should be used in the construction, so that's what I mean by "alter".

Here the constant $C$ in the two bounds for $f$ and for the Wasserstein ball is the same, and you want the sequence $\nu_n$ in the same ball of the radius $C$, and with the same limit $R$ of the integrals, do you?

Ah sorry, no the $C$ being the same was by accident, let me edit the post to make it clearer. I also forgot to mention that $\mu_n$ and $\nu_n$ should both have the same limit in $W_1$.

(also, is the strict inequality $<C$ strictly required? :)

Yes, I used it when I constructed my sequence $\mu_n$, so indeed I do need the strict inequality :D
